# How can I launch google photos app from within Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

When using

```
Launcher.OpenAsync("http://maps.google.com")
```

the google maps application opens beautifully but with

```
Launcher.OpenAsync("http://photos.google.com")
```

it opens the application in browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.launcher.openasync?view=xamarin-essentials),

> the `OpenAsync(String)` Launches the app specified by the uri scheme

So if you set the url like below it'll start the google photos application.I tested it on my side and it does open the application.

```
 await Launcher.OpenAsync("http://photos.google.com");
```

**Update:**

If you want to launch the app respectively, please try use the following format of links:

```
for instagram
instagram://user?username=yourUserName

for twitter
twitter://userName?user_id=userId

for facebook
fb://page/page_id
```

Comment: In my case, it opens the Google Photos app through Google Chrome. I would like it to go straight to the Google Photos app. Even better if I could choose a specific album.

Comment: I'm not sure that  the launch url of  Google Photos. I've updated other app's launch url for your reference.